# Add prefixes to word groups in Python

Tags: python, string, prefix

How can I add a prefix to each single word in a given word group using .join function?

> :param vocab_words: list of vocabulary words with a prefix.
> :return: str of prefix followed by vocabulary words with
> prefix applied, separated by ' :: '.

```
This function takes a `vocab_words` list and returns a string
with the prefix  and the words with prefix applied, separated
 by ' :: '. "
```

I understand that prefix is always vocab_words[0] in the string.

I tried

```
 def make_word_groups(vocab_words):
    return ' :: ' .join(vocab_words[0] for i in vocab_words[0:])
```

It does not work. I am getting AssertionError. As a result - lot of prefixes and only then some words with prefixes.

Comment: Would you like to give some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: input_data = ['auto', 'didactic',  'graph', 'mate',  'chrome',  'centric',  'complete',
             'echolalia',  'encoder', 'biography'] input_data = ['en' ,'circle', 'fold', 'close','joy', 'lighten', 'tangle', 'able', 'code', 'culture'] input_data = ['pre', 'serve', 'dispose', 'position', 'requisite',  'digest',
              'natal', 'addressed', 'adolescent', 'assumption', 'mature', 'compute'] I have four groups of words with different prefixes

Comment: And result_data = ('auto :: autodidactic :: autograph :: automate :: autochrome :: '
              'autocentric :: autocomplete :: autoecholalia :: autoencoder :: '
              'autobiography')

Comment: Your result seems inconsistent. Please check that

Comment: If I am guessing correct then your output should be `auto :: autodidactic :: autograph :: automate :: autochrome :: autocentric :: autocomplete :: autoecholalia :: autoencoder :: autobiography`, am i right?

Comment: Yes, Expected auto :: autodidactic :: autograph :: automate :: autochrome :: autocentric :: autocomplete :: autoecholalia :: autoencoder :: autobiography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def make_word_groups(vocab_words):
   separator = ' :: '

   prefix = vocab_words[0]
   words = vocab_words[1:]

   prefixed_words = [prefix + word for word in words]
   result = prefix + separator + separator.join(prefixed_words)

   return result
```

Comment: I have tried and got this AssertionError: 'autodidactic :: autograph :: automate :: auto[82 chars]aphy' != 'auto :: autodidactic :: autograph :: automate[90 chars]aphy'
- autodidactic :: autograph :: automate :: autochrome :: autocentric :: autocomplete :: autoecholalia :: autoencoder :: autobiography
+ auto :: autodidactic :: autograph :: automate :: autochrome :: autocentric :: autocomplete :: autoecholalia :: autoencoder :: autobiography
? ++++++++

Comment: share the full code snippet for better understanding

Comment: ok looking at your exected result let me change my answer

Comment: check again please

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```py
def make_word_groups(vocab_words):
    result_data = f'{vocab_words[0]} :: '
    result_data += ' :: '.join([vocab_words[0] + word for word in vocab_words[1:]])
    return result_data

input_data = ['auto', 'didactic', 'graph', 'mate', 'chrome', 'centric', 'complete', 'echolalia', 'encoder', 'biography']
print(make_word_groups(input_data))
input_data = ['en' ,'circle', 'fold', 'close','joy', 'lighten', 'tangle', 'able', 'code', 'culture']
print(make_word_groups(input_data))
input_data = ['pre', 'serve', 'dispose', 'position', 'requisite', 'digest', 'natal', 'addressed', 'adolescent', 'assumption', 'mature', 'compute']
print(make_word_groups(input_data))
```

**Output:**

```
auto :: autodidactic :: autograph :: automate :: autochrome :: autocentric :: autocomplete :: autoecholalia :: autoencoder :: autobiography
en :: encircle :: enfold :: enclose :: enjoy :: enlighten :: entangle :: enable :: encode :: enculture
pre :: preserve :: predispose :: preposition :: prerequisite :: predigest :: prenatal :: preaddressed :: preadolescent :: preassumption :: premature :: precompute
```

Comment: Welcome :), If it's worked then please accept this answer and give an upvote. check here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
def make_word_groups(vocab_words):
    prefix = vocab_words[0]
    vocabulary_words = vocab_words[1:]
    for i in range(len(vocabulary_words)):
        vocabulary_words[i] = prefix + vocabulary_words[i]
    vocabulary_words = [prefix] + vocabulary_words
    result = ' :: '.join(vocabulary_words)
    return result
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).